# $f$ identification, image connected, fibers connected implies domain connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $p:A\longrightarrow B$ be an identification, $B$ a connected space and $p^{-1}(b)$ connected $\forall\;b\in B$. I want to proof that $A$ is a connected space. I proceed as follows:

Suppose $U,V\subset A$ are disjoint non-empty open subsets such that $U\cup V=A$. I want to show that $p(U)$ and $p(V)$ are disjoint non-empty open subset with $p(U)\cup p(V)=B$.  $\forall b\in B$, $p^{-1}(b)\subset U$ or $p^{-1}(b)\subset V$ because $p^{-1}(b)$ is connected

- $p(U)\cup p(V)=p(U\cup V)=p(A)=B$
- Let $b\in p(U)\cap p(V)$.

  $b\in p(U)\Longrightarrow\exists\;a_1\in U \mid p(a_1)=b\Longrightarrow p^{-1}(b)\cap U \neq \emptyset$

  $b\in p(V)\Longrightarrow\exists\;a_2\in V \mid p(a_2)=b\Longrightarrow p^{-1}(b)\cap V \neq \emptyset$

  This can't happen because $p^{-1}(b)\subset U$ or $p^{-1}(b)\subset V$. So $p(U)\cap p(V)=\emptyset$
- Now I would have to prove that $p(U)$ and $p(V)$ are open. To check if $p(U)$ is open, I have to look if $p^{-1}(p(U))$ is open. I think $p^{-1}(p(U))=U$ but I can't prove $p^{-1}(p(U))\subset U$ (the other is trivial). My attempt is:

  Let $a\in p^{-1}(p(U))\Longrightarrow p(a)\in p(U)$. Being that $p^{-1}(\{p(a)\})$ is connected, then $a\in p^{-1}(\{p(a)\})\subset U$ or $a\in p^{-1}(\{p(a)\})\subset V$, and the second one can not happen because that would imply $p(a)\in p(V)$ and $p(U)\cap p(V)=\emptyset$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s correct, except that you’ve used both $p$ and $f$ for the map. Another way to say the same thing, perhaps slightly clearer:

> Every fibre of $p$ is contained in exactly one of $U$ and $V$. If $a\in p^{-1}\big[p[U]\big]$, then $p(a)=p(u)$ for some $u\in U$, and therefore $a$ and $u$ are in the same fibre of $p$; clearly $u\in U$, so this fibre is contained in $U$, and therefore $a\in U$.